On windows cannot start a compiled python code as a service
I have the following code :
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import os

class MyService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "MyService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "My Service"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        servicemanager.LogMsg(
            servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
            servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
            (self._svc_name_, "")
        )
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        print("test")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyService)

I compiled it using "pyinstaller --onefile MyService.py". It creates a MyService.exe. I created a service MyService usin "sc create" command and the service was created. However when I try to start the service I get the error message 1053 The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
I tried increasing registry value Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServicesPipeTimeout to 240000 (twice the default) but it doesn't help.
I don't see what is wrong here thnaks in advance for your advice.
